# Transferring Values in nested dictionaries/lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 3, 2], 
        [2, 3, 1, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3, 0]]
```

I would like to check if the number 1 is in the third column of all the nested lists, if it is than it should replace the 1 with a 0 and the 2 in that list with a 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have posted more code that most people are going to want to sort through.  Try reducing your post to a **minimal**, reproducible example, with a desired output.

Comment: @James Sorted it out, could you please answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
nested_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 3, 2], 
                [2, 3, 1, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3, 0]]

for list_ in nested_lists:

    if list_[2] == 1:

        list_[2] = 0
        list_    = [1 if n == 2 else n for n in list_]
```

After execution, `nested_lists` goes from the given

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 3, 2], 
 [2, 3, 1, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3, 0]]
```

To

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 3, 2]
 [1, 3, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 3, 0]]
```